# apache mahout for text in spanish

Tags: java, apache, mahout

Does anyone know if Apache Mahout works well with text in spanish? I need to do some clustering over newspaper articles in spanish and there are not a lot of tools for doing it. I think Mahout is a cool framework to do this, but is it good working on spanish text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not? You can use `seq2sparse` command of `bin/mahout` script and specify corresponding Lucene analyzer (`org.apache.lucene.analysis.es.SpanishAnalyzer`) using the `-a` option. See chapter 8 (pages 199-200...) of Mahout in Action book.

Besides this, you can also write your own analyzer, using existing ones. The book contains many examples, and you can find source code [in repository](https://github.com/tdunning/MiA).